# Unable to add letter to drive in windows

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I have two drives in my computer, but one doesn't show up in file explorer. It shows up in disk management, but I'm unable to assign a letter, as the option, as well as all others other than "delete volume" are greyed out. When selecting the second drive in diskpart, it shows the correct disk as selected, but lists the volumes of the first disk, even down to the drive letter. When attempting to access the drive via the run box with the address from the `mountvol` command, I am denied access and am told I need to use the security tab, but no such tab exists in the properties menu, only "General," "Tools," "Hardware," and "Customize." There is an os on the disk, namely ubuntu, as well as a bunch of files I want to move from that disk to windows. I can access the windows drive from ubuntu if nothing else, but I would prefer to have access to the ubuntu files from windows.

Comment: What filesystem format(s) are on the partition(s) on the second disk?  Windows can only read NTFS, FAT and exFAT.  If the partition(s) on your second disk are formatted with a different filesystem, (e.g. ext3), Windows won't be able to mount it and read the files.

Comment: You might consider providing one or a couple of pictures instead of describing what you see.